# After running node server i am not able to access it

Tags: node.js

I am new in Node so My question is this

```
var http = require('http');
   http.createServer(function(request,response){

     response.writeHead(200);
     response.write('Hello, World');
     response.end();
   });
   console.log('Howdy');
```

Now When I run This and try to access `localhost:5050` i get Nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't listening to any port so add `.listen(5050)`:

```
var http = require('http'); 
http.createServer(function(request,response){

  response.writeHead(200);
  response.write('Hello, World');
  response.end();
}).listen(5050);
console.log('Howdy');
```